# ORacle Maintaining multiple sequence in same column based on a group

Tags: oracle, sequence

I am having a table containing a list of orders received from various offices in the same organization eg:

```
    --------------------------------------
    |Order-ID | Office-ID | Order-Details|
    --------------------------------------
    |10000001 | 100       |xxyxxxx       |
    |10000002 | 100       |xxyxxxx       |
    |10000003 | 100       |xxyxxxx       |
    |10100001 | 101       |xxyxxxx       |
    |10200001 | 102       |xxyxxxx       |
    |10200002 | 102       |xxyxxxx       |
    |10300001 | 103       |xxyxxxx       |
    --------------------------------------
```

Order Id is to be generated in a sequence manner for each office ID, ie first order from office 100 will be 10000001 (100-00001), second one will be 10000002 (100-00002), third order form office 103 will be 10300001 (103-00003) and so on.
It is ok even if field 100-00002 is stored in the form of 2 columns (as in 1NF). How this type of sequence can be maintained in oracle without impacting concurrent users? But there should not be any gap in the serial number given to orders (which is not guaranteed in oracle sequence and also it is not feasible to maintain multiple sequences as number of offices will be 10000+).

Comment: In general is it not good to have redundant data. But what do you mean by "...can be maintained in oracle without impacting concurrent users". Creating numbers guarantied without any gap is generally a challenge in a multi-user environment.

Comment: To get a gap-less sequence of ID's you need *serialization*. The crutial point here is, do you have *concurrent processing* on the **same office**. With 10K+ offices you should manage it that each office is processed only by one process (assuming this is a batch process). This enables a trival solution with a DIY transaction backed sequence (= helper table with a current key for each office).

Comment: For your first question, it seems like you could generate the order IDs from a single sequence and then add `office_id * 100000`. Or, keep them as separate columns but combine them in a virtual column, which you could even index if you wanted to. The 'gap-free sequence' issue is harder. You will need to either serialise inserts while handling rollbacks, or else link to a separate table of preallocated order numbers.

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit: I cannot insert into table x(serialno) values(select max(serialno)+1) to ensure a continuous serial number since concurrent users in the middle of transaction will not get correct max values

Comment: @ Marmite Bomber: It is a web application. So a batch job is not possible

Comment: what happens to the sequence if an order fails ??

Comment: There is no question of failed orders, continuous numbering should be present for all orders. Oracle sequence may have gaps as per the documentation and our experience.